# Hexacode converted into character

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have XML in place which has hexadecimal character but whenever I am ingesting and downloading it from MarkLogic database MarkLogic is converting them into their original character. For example, in XML I have

```
<copyright-holder>&#x00A9; 2015 &#x2014; All rights reserved &#x00A9; Standards Australia Limited</copyright-holder>
```

which has been converted to

```
<copyright-holder>© 2015 — All rights reserved © Standards Australia Limited</copyright-holder>
```

I am using document insert function to load document into the ML DB. How I can retain hexadeciamal/entities in XML? Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MarkLogic processes XML when inserted into the database, but you can tell it to produce entities when it serializes it. You can set output options on groups and app-servers, but you can also mimic that idea using `xdmp:quote` to get a quick impression of what you would get:

```
xdmp:quote(
  <copyright-holder>&#x00A9; 2015 &#x2014; All rights reserved &#x00A9; Standards Australia Limited</copyright-holder>,
  map:entry("outputEncoding", "us-ascii")
)
```

HTH!

Comment: It is converting &#x00A9; to &#169;.

Comment: Yes, that is the decimal version of xA9. It has the exact same meaning..

Comment: Not sure why you'd need that. You can always normalize both sides if you need to compare.  Or if you need the xml unchanges, store it as binary. But you won't be able to apply indexes in that case

Answer (score 1):

XML serialization is discussed at [XML serialization and output options](https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/328/0/xml-serialization-and-output-options)